# Object doesn't support property or method 'getAttributeNS' Error on IE only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when i am trying to run the following html statement, I am getting error on IE only not in Chrome

```
document.getElementById("Colors").options[i].style.display = "none";
```

any alternate for to hide dropdown values that will reflect in IE?

Comment: Please provide the error and some more information about your system

Comment: [javascript != java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: Not sure how that error goes with your code, but as you've tagged this [jquery] then `$("#Colors>options:eq(i)").hide();`

Comment: Please share your html code